# C# SQL command line monodevelop

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am running monodevelop on arch linux and I tried to insert some values into a local database , but when I run it from a button the application closes.The file is created and it have all fields.
Here is my code:

```
SqliteConnection m_dbConnection = new SqliteConnection ("Data Source=GOOD_FOOD.sqlite;Version=3;");
        m_dbConnection.Open ();

        int id;
        string get = "SELECT LAST(id_client) FROM Clienti";
        SqliteCommand comSelect = new SqliteCommand (get, m_dbConnection);

        int? getid = (int?)comSelect.ExecuteScalar();
        if (getid.HasValue) {
            id = Convert.ToInt32(getid) + 1;
        } else 
        {
            id = 1;
        }

        // create account

        string create = "INSERT INTO Clienti (id_client, parola, nume, prenume, adresa, email) VALUES (@id, @parola, @nume, @prenume, @adresa, @email)";
        SqliteCommand createcmd = new SqliteCommand (create, m_dbConnection);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@parola", password.Text);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", name.Text);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@prenume", secondname.Text);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa", address.Text);
        createcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ("@email", email.Text);
        createcmd.ExecuteNonQuery ();

        m_dbConnection.Close ();
```

Comment: Why `id =  Convert.ToInt32(getid) + 1;` when `getid` is already a nullable `int`? Should just be `id = getid.Value +1;`. Also, are you running in debug mode, and not in release mode? Atleast monodevelop should halt at an exception if it throws one and show you the line where the error is. An absolute crash without an exception is quite weird .

Comment: I will try like that .

Comment: Ok , SQLite error no such function LAST

Comment: I tried SELECT id_client FROM Clienti ORDER BY id_client DESC and it worked, thanks , I forgot about try catch

Comment: You could write an answer to this question and accept it yourself then, then question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The soulution :
Use try{} catch{} and change id = Convert.ToInt32(getid) + 1; to id = getid.Value +1;
Change "SELECT LAST(id_client) FROM Clienti"; to "SELECT id_client FROM Clienti ORDER BY id_client DESC;";